# MPI_Scatterv: processing time significantly more when array size not a multiple of ranks

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

Distributing a global array into smaller local arrays and later gathering the local arrays back into the global array.

Used MPI_Scatterv() (only called once) and MPI_Gatherv() (called in a loop).

```
... some code

for j = 0 to nprocs-1
  displs[j] = (int)j*global_size/nprocs;
  counts[j] = (int)(global_size(j+1)*/nprocs)-(int)(global_size*j/nprocs);

... test (checks), this ensures the best size distribution

... all arrays are pointers with allocated sizes as per above

MPI_Scatterv(global_array,counts,displs,type,
local_array,counts[rank],type,root,comm);

... begins loop (every rank does this whole loop)

... some calculations, inner loops divided between ranks

MPI_Allgatherv(local_array,counts[rank],type,
global_array,counts,displs,type,comm);

... some calculations, inner loops divided between ranks
```

This works. Sort of. If global_size%nprocs == 0, I get the expected speed ups. If not, I get a drastic increase in processing time. The code load is based on global_size.

Is this known behavior? Perhaps a known problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a clear description on how you build, execute and measure the code.

Comment: Also knowing the MPI library will help.

Comment: OK, it seems that when `global_size%nprocs == 0`, you are basically doing a Scatter, not a Scatterv. By definition, it's faster because it's something easy to do. When the sizes are different, you don't have the same speedup, but you need to provide the library and the version with a [mcve] to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I did make a minimal code in order to post here but doing so made me realise it wasn't Scatterv, but rather something else slowing down the code. I've isolated the problem to a Gather call, unrelated to the Scatterv call. The Gather call had been made inside one of the loops which depended on the local size, which is causing the code to hang as some processes have larger loops. Not sure why the code is even working.